# Decoding url within encoded parameters (returnUrl)

Tags: javascript, url, uri, decode, url-parameters

I want to retrieve some parameters inside an url using multiples times the parameter « returnUrl ».

Example:

```
HTTPS://force.com?positionId=a0w0X000007HjBuQAK&lang=fr&mediaChannel=a0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX&returnUrl=https%253A%2F%2force.com%2Fcxsrec__cxsSearchDetail%3Fid%3Da0w0X000007HjBuQAK%26lang%3Dfr%26mediaChannel%3Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX%26returnUrl%3Dhttps%253A%2F%2force.com%2Fcxsrec__cxsSearch%253Flang%253Dfr%2526mediaChannel%253Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQA%2526 site%253DFrance%2526hcFilter%253Da0Z0X00000XiFF3UAN%252Ca0Z0X00000XiUqTUAV%2526orderBy%253DPosition_name__c%2526orderDir%253Dasc%2526mediaChannel%253Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX%26lang%3Dfr%26mediaChannel%3Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX’
```

?...**returnUrl**%3Dhttps%253A%2F%2force.com%2Fcxsrec__cxsSearch%253Flang%253Dfr%2526mediaChannel%253Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQA%2526**site**%253DFrance%2526hcFilter...

I want to get the value of the parameter **site**.

I tried to used **decodeURI** function and then **searchParams.get("site")** but **decodeURI** it is not decoding the parameters after **returnUrl**.

Is there another function to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

I've deleted a space before `site` in the URL:

```js
const url1 = new URL('https://force.com?positionId=a0w0X000007HjBuQAK&lang=fr&mediaChannel=a0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX&returnUrl=https%253A%2F%2force.com%2Fcxsrec__cxsSearchDetail%3Fid%3Da0w0X000007HjBuQAK%26lang%3Dfr%26mediaChannel%3Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX%26returnUrl%3Dhttps%253A%2F%2force.com%2Fcxsrec__cxsSearch%253Flang%253Dfr%2526mediaChannel%253Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQA%2526site%253DFrance%2526hcFilter%253Da0Z0X00000XiFF3UAN%252Ca0Z0X00000XiUqTUAV%2526orderBy%253DPosition_name__c%2526orderDir%253Dasc%2526mediaChannel%253Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX%26lang%3Dfr%26mediaChannel%3Da0o0X00000EGQ5TQAX');
const params1 = new URLSearchParams(url1.search);
const returnUrl = params1.get('returnUrl');

const url2 = new URL(decodeURIComponent(returnUrl));
const params2 = new URLSearchParams(url2.search);
const site = params2.get('site');

console.log(site);
```

See some details in [`encodeURIComponent()` description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description)

Comment: Working fine.. thanks a lot. I just replace **const** with **var** to be recognized in GTM.